# How to select data order by sort value and sort NULL By name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I wrote following SQL query to select data from `@tmp` table variable.

```
SELECT @rowCount AS [row-count],
       t.[row-no] AS [row-no],
       t.[ServiceID] AS ServiceID,
       t.ServiceName AS ServiceName,
       t.[BranchServiceSortValue] AS SortValue,
       (CASE WHEN t.OptIn = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS OptIn
FROM   @tmp t
       INNER JOIN dbo.Category
            ON  Category.CategoryId = t.FkCategoryId
       INNER JOIN dbo.ServiceType
            ON  ServiceType.ServiceTypeId = t.FkServiceTypeId
WHERE  t.[row-no] >= @startRow
       AND t.[row-no] <= @endRow

       ORDER BY t.BranchServiceSortValue,t.serviceName
```

According to the data in `@tmp` table,my above query return following output.

```
| row-count | row-no | ServiceID | ServiceName | SortValue | OptIn |
|-----------|--------|-----------|-------------|-----------|-------|
| 24        | 4      | 1088      | AAB         | NULL      | No    |
| 24        | 5      | 1089      | AAC         | NULL      | No    |
| 24        | 6      | 1090      | AAD         | NULL      | No    |

| 24        | 1      | 1093      | GDGD        | 0         | Yes   |
| 24        | 7      | 1091      | EETETE      | 1         | Yes   |
| 24        | 8      | 1092      | CSCDF       | 2         | Yes   |
| 24        | 3      | 1086      | CXCX        | 3         | Yes   |
| 24        | 9      | 16        | ASA         | 4         | Yes   |
| 24        | 2      | 1087      | BFB         | 5         | Yes   |
| 24        | 10     | 7         | Mortgage    | 6         | Yes   |
| 24        | 11     | 17        | DDWW        | 7         | Yes   |
| 24        | 12     | 11        | IL          | 8         | Yes   |
| 24        | 13     | 5         | SAA         | 9         | Yes   |
| 24        | 14     | 9         | CD          | 10        | Yes   |
```

You can see according to my above query data rows are sorted by `SortValue` and when `SortValue = NULL`, those 3 rows sorted by its `ServiceName`,

But `I need to display`SortValue = NULL`rows at the bottom of the other rows`.Its mean I need to display Null rows after the `SortValue` Not NULL data and **`SortValue = NULL` should be display order by its ServiceName**.

My Expected Output is:

```
| row-count | row-no | ServiceID | ServiceName | SortValue | OptIn |
|-----------|--------|-----------|-------------|-----------|-------|
| 14        | 1      | 1093      | GDGD        | 0         | Yes   |
| 14        | 7      | 1091      | EETETE      | 1         | Yes   |
| 14        | 8      | 1092      | CSCDF       | 2         | Yes   |
| 14        | 3      | 1086      | CXCX        | 3         | Yes   |
| 14        | 9      | 16        | ASA         | 4         | Yes   |
| 14        | 2      | 1087      | BFB         | 5         | Yes   |
| 14        | 10     | 7         | Mortgage    | 6         | Yes   |
| 14        | 11     | 17        | DDWW        | 7         | Yes   |
| 14        | 12     | 11        | IL          | 8         | Yes   |
| 14        | 13     | 5         | SAA         | 9         | Yes   |
| 14        | 14     | 9         | CD          | 10        | Yes   |

| 14        | 4      | 1088      | AAB         | NULL      | No    |
| 14        | 5      | 1089      | AAC         | NULL      | No    |
| 14        | 6      | 1090      | AAD         | NULL      | No    |
```

How should I need to change my query to get above output? please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` has the lowest value, so you'll need to use a `CASE` to put `NULL` at the end, and then sort by `SortValue`:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.BranchServiceSortValue IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         t.BranchServiceSortValue,
         t.serviceName;
```

Comment: most of the time you helped my problems. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Just add a key to the `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN t.BranchServiceSortValue IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         t.BranchServiceSortValue, t.serviceName
```

The SQL standard provides the options `NULLS FIRST` and `NULLS LAST` for `ORDER BY` clauses.  SQL Server does not (yet) implement these.

Comment: And great explanation